# Use Nvidia GPU with Unity3D for game development

Tags: nvidia, gpu, unity, 3d

I am using Unity3D on Arch Linux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unity3D for game development.

I have a Nvidia GTX 1650. All my nvidia packages are up to date (tensorflow-gpu for example works fine). But when I run a game within unity3D it does not use the GPU at all.

How can I instruct unity3D to use the GPU when developing games?

Details of my GPU below:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.27       Driver Version: 465.27       CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   53C    P8     2W /  N/A |      4MiB /  3914MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       615      G   /usr/lib/Xorg                       4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the issue was due to my laptop's hybrid Intel/Nvidia setup defaulting to the Intel graphics over the dedicated graphics card.

This can be fixed by using [Nvidia-Optimus](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus) to instruct the machine to use the dedicated GPU for rendering particular applications using [PRIME](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PRIME#PRIME_render_offload):

`sudo pacman -S nvidia nvidia-prime`

`prime-run unityhub`